# Secured WebSocket connection not working in FireFox and Chrome in MAC OS?

Tags: angular, https, websocket, httpserver, wss

I am having two applications one in server and another one is client application. In server I am creating webSocket and in client I am creating we webSocket client.

Here I am getting Error (FireFox and Chrome) while creating webSocket client (in safari it is working fine).

I followed HTTPS configuration step  which is in the [link](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a)

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8443/ws/v1/user/userId=user1'
```

`failed: Error in connection establishment:` `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

```
connect @   
web-socket.ts:53
    setTimeout  @   
web-socket.ts:86
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask    @   zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask   @   zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask    @   zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @   zone.js:485
timer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and chrome  will keep on giving you error until you open up a separate tab and do try hitting URL https://localhost:8443 and Confirm Security Exception. Then try it will work.